# What does "int &= 0xFF" in a checksum do?

Tags: c#, bitwise-operators

I implemented this checksum algorithm I found, and it works fine but I can't figure out what this "&= 0xFF" line is actually doing.

I looked up the bitwise & operator, and wikipedia claims it's a logical AND of all the bits in A with B.  I also read that 0xFF is equivalent to 255 -- which should mean that all of the bits are 1.  If you take any number & 0xFF, wouldn't that be the identity of the number?  So A & 0xFF produces A, right?

So then I thought, wait a minute, checksum in the code below is a 32 bit Int, but 0xFF is 8bit.  Does that mean that the result of checksum &= 0xFF is that 24 bits end up as zeros and only the remaining 8 bits are kept?  In which case, checksum is truncated to 8 bits.  Is that what's going on here?

```
    private int CalculateChecksum(byte[] dataToCalculate)
    {
        int checksum = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < dataToCalculate.Length; i++)
        {
            checksum += dataToCalculate[i];
        }

        //What does this line actually do?
        checksum &= 0xff;

        return checksum;
    }
```

Also, if the result is getting truncated to 8 bits, is that because 32 bits is pointless in a checksum? Is it possible to have a situation where a 32 bit checksum catches corrupt data when 8 bit checksum doesn't?

Comment: The += operator is in general going to produce a value that is larger than 255.  But a simple checksum generally only takes one byte in the protocol.  So &= 0xff throws away the upper bits.  Simply declaring the checksum variable as byte would have been easier.

Comment: @HansPassant Using `int` is a little more performant (in debug mode about 10% on a 500mb buffer on my machine), not noticeable for small data sets but could make a difference when you are talking something in the gigabyte range or doing a lot of operations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like you have a good understanding of the situation.

> Does that mean that the result of checksum &= 0xFF is that 24 bits end up as zeros and only the remaining 8 bits are kept?

Yes.

> Is it possible to have a situation where a 32 bit checksum catches corrupt data when 8 bit checksum doesn't?

Yes.

Answer (score 8):

It is masking off the higher bytes, leaving only the lower byte.

```
checksum &= 0xFF;
```

Is syntactically short for:

```
checksum = checksum & 0xFF;
```

Which, since it is doing integer operations, the `0xFF` gets expanded into an `int`:

```
checksum = checksum & 0x000000FF;
```

Which masks off the upper 3 bytes and returns the lower byte as an integer (not a byte).

To answer your other question: Since a 32-bit checksum is much wider than an 8-bit checksum, it can catch errors that an 8-bit checksum would not, but both sides need to use the same checksum calculations for that to work.

Comment: It might be my lack of sleep, but isn't it masking off *everything but* the lower byte?

Answer (score 3):

This is performing a simple checksum on the bytes (8 bit values) by adding them and ignoring any overflow out into higher order bits.  The final &=0xFF, as you suspected, just truncates the value to the 8LSB of the 32 bit (If that is your compiler's definition of int) value resulting in an unsigned value between 0 and 255.

The truncation to 8 bits and throwing away the higher order bits is simply the algorithm defined for this checksum implementation.  Historically this sort of check value was used to provide some confidence that a block of bytes had been transferred over a simple serial interface correctly.

To answer your last question then yes, a 32 bit check value will be able to detect an error that would not be detected with an 8 bit check value.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the checksum is truncated to 8 bits by the 
`&= 0xFF.` The lowest 8 bits are kept and all higher bits are set to 0.

Narrowing the checksum to 8 bits does decrease the reliability. Just think of two 32bit checksums that are different but the lowest 8 bits are equal. In case of truncating to 8 bits both would be equal, in 32bit case they are not.